# PrimeFaces components don't display while standard JSF components render fine

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Java EE6/CDI JSF2 Primefaces 3.3.1.  I created a search page with a few cascading dropdowns that are used to generate a table of search results  If I use jsf:

```
<h:dataTable  var="_employeeVList" value="#{employeeVProducer.employeeVList}"  rendered="#{not empty employeeVProducer.employeeVList}"> 
    <f:facet name="header">  
        Employee Search Results 
    </f:facet>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Area</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{_employeeVList.areaName}" />
    </h:column>
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

The table renders with output, html looks normal.  But when I change to primefaces:

```
<p:dataTable  var="_employeeVList" value="#{employeeVProducer.employeeVList}"  rendered="#{not empty employeeVProducer.employeeVList}"> 
    <f:facet name="header">  
        Employee Search Results 
    </f:facet>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Area</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{_employeeVList.areaName}" />
    </p:column>
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

The table doesn't display.  When I look at the source with firebug I see some weirdness with the html:

```
    <table id="searchForm:results">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p:datatable rendered="true" value="[com.raytheon.myPkg.EmployeeV@f486,                                 com.raytheon.myPkg.EmployeeV@88fe,                              com.raytheon.myPkg.EmployeeV@adaf, 
                                          ...
                                com.raytheon.myPkg.EmployeeV@6a5b]" 
var="_employeeVList">
    <p:column></p:column>
    <p:column></p:column>
    ...                          
    </p:datatable></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

The objects are in the tag label, the columns are empty.
Elsewhere in the page I'm using p:panelGrid, that contains the dropdowns and that displays correctly.

I have h:head and h:body in my default template page.

The table is backed by a stateful request scoped bean.

I'm not using any external JavaScript.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thus, the `<p:xxx>` tags are not been parsed as JSF tags at all and appear plain vanilla in the generated HTML output. That can have one or more of the following reasons:

1. You forgot to declare the `p:` XML namespace in the view, or you used the wrong namespace URI. It should be:

   ```
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
   ```
2. You forgot to actually install the PrimeFaces library. It should be a matter of either

   a. Dropping `primefaces.jar` in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

   b. Making sure your dependency manager (e.g. Maven) has been configured to add PrimeFaces to the project and added it to the runtime `/WEB-INF/lib` folder

Comment: doh, the namespace was the first thing I checked - apparently not close enough.  Thanx @BalusC

Answer (score -1):

To add one other reason to BalusC's list:

If you don't add servlet URL mapping to your URL, you will get weird output and JSF won't parse your XHTML pages!

For example, if you have the following URL mapping in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

you should use `/faces/yourpage.xhtml` to render the output correctly by JSF.

If you use `/yourpage.xhtml` you will see weird output.

Comment: Indeed, but in OP's particular case, the `<h:dataTable>` worked, so I scrathed that possibility :)