# Configure PrimeFaces with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, primefaces

So this is my first time building an Java EE application. I watched a lot of tutorials but most of them are using eclipse.

So the problem is this:

```
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{loginBean.login()}"
                             styleClass="btn btn-info" value="Login" />
        </h:panelGroup>
```

When I start Wildfly server and try to access the login page. If there are no 
brackets after the login method I get:

The class 'LoginBean' does not have the property login.

If I try it with the brackets. The method is invoked when page is initialized and I get exception that the values for username and pass are null.
When I commented the method content I got the page to initialize properly, but another issue occured. 
The JSF components like:

```
<h:panelGroup>
            <h3 class="loginTitle">#{msgs['default.title']}</h3>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Are rendered correctly, but the Primefaces components

```
 <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.username}" id="username"
                         styleClass="loginInputField" required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Username is required field">
                <p:watermark for="username" value="Username" />
            </p:inputText>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

Are rendered with 0px height and width.

Here is my LoginBean.java

public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

```
private static final String SUCCESS_LOGIN_REDIRECT = "/pages/success?faces-redirect=true";
private static final String LOGIN_PAGE_REDIRECT = "/pages/login?faces-redirect=true";

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private HttpServletRequest request;

private String username;
private String password;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    //TODO
}

public String login() {
    username = "";
    password = "";
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(username) || StringUtils.isBlank(password)) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new  FacesMessage("Invalid Credentials"));
        return "";
    } else if ("admin".equals(username) && "123".equals(password)) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("LOGGED_USER", username);
        return SUCCESS_LOGIN_REDIRECT;
    }

    MessageUtils.addErrorMessage("login.error.invalid.credentials");
    return "";
}

public String logout() {
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    return LOGIN_PAGE_REDIRECT;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

And last here is my project structure https://github.com/M-Veselinov/Java-EE
I think that I'm doing something wrong with web.xml or other config files, but I have no idea what.
I'll appreciate some help. Thanks.

Client Source:

```
<p:inputtext id="username" styleclass="loginInputField" required="true" requiredmessage="Username is required field">
                <p:watermark for="username" value="Username"></p:watermark>
</p:inputtext>
```

Comment: how does the source at the client look like? Do you see a `<p:commandButton...` there?

Comment: Yes, it has. I updated my question with a snippet.

Comment: Duplicate then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201356/primefaces-components-dont-display-while-standard-jsf-components-render-fine?rq=1

Comment: I've seen this question, and I think my problem is exactly within the lib folder. But I'm not sure where to put it. When I created the project IntelliJ created it in the root directory of the project. I tried moving in WEB-INF but it still don't work.

Comment: If you've seen that question, next time mention those things (see [ask]) Then this question is not jsf, primefaces or jsf-2 related but a plain intellij-ide one... (it is better btw to use a deployment/packaging/... mechanism this is independent of your ide, but which does integrate with it, e.g. maven)

Comment: I'll try with maven, I tried once but I'll try again :D

Comment: I didn't say you should use maven directly now. It's more a suggestion